# Active admin with JW player

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, jwplayer

I integrated Acive admin (activeadmin-0.6.0) in my project. I have some videos need to play in admin panel. In my application i used JW Player to play the videos. How can i include this into my admin panel show view

Comment: Does the admin panel allow you to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard video_tag ;)

I use it like this in my show page:

```
panel "Clip" do
    video_tag("trailer.ogg",:controls=>true,:autobuffer=>true,:size=>"640x480")
end
```